# PayPal sandbox ipn status never verified

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm testing a PayPal ipn listener and it seems it NEVER returns VERIFIED status... Here's the script :

```
<?php
//read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}

//post back to PayPal system to validate
$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Host:www.sandbox.paypal.com\r\n";
$header .= "Connection: close\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
//$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30); 
//

//error connecting to paypal
if (!$fp) {
    //
}

//successful connection    
if ($fp) {
    fputs ($fp, $header . $req);

    //while (!feof($fp)) {
    $res = stream_get_contents($fp, 1024);
        //$res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
        $res = trim($res); //NEW & IMPORTANT

        if (strcmp($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
            // if status is COMPLETED insert order into database
            if ($_POST['payment_status'] == "Completed") {
                $subject = 'Instant Payment Notification - COMPLETED';
                 $to = 'my_email_address@gmail.com';    //  your email
                 $body =  "An instant payment notification was successfully recieved\n";
                 $body .= "from ".$_POST['payer_email']." on ".date('m/d/Y');
                 $body .= " at ".date('g:i A')."\n\nDetails:\n";

                 foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) { $body .= "\n".$key." : ".$value; }
                 mail($to, $subject, $body); 
            }             
        }

        else {
            //insert into DB in a table for bad payments for you to process later
            $subject = 'Instant Payment Notification - ELSE status';
             $to = 'my_email_address@gmail.com';    //  your email
             $body =  "Else clause \n";
             $body .= "from ".$_POST['payer_email']." on ".date('m/d/Y');
             $body .= " at ".date('g:i A')."\n\nDetails:\n";

             foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) { $body .= "\n".$key." : ".$value; }
             mail($to, $subject, $body);
        }
    //}

    fclose($fp);
} 

?>
```

I've tried the code with **while (!feof($fp))** and **$res = fgets ($fp, 1024)**
I never get the VERIFIED email and I'm even not sure if it is a coding issue... That's why I'm asking here : maybe some of you had this problem before and can help me. Thanks in advance.

OK, here is the $res posted back :

```
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Date: Wed, 26 Feb 2014 12:03:23 GMT
    Server: Apache
    domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
    Set-Cookie: cookie_check=yes; expires=Sat, 24-Feb-2024 12:03:24 GMT;domain=.paypal.com;     path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: navcmd=_notify-validate; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: navlns=0.0; expires=Fri, 26-Feb-2016 12:03:24 GMT; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: Apache=10.72.109.11.1393416203743713; path=/; expires=Fri, 19-Feb-44 12:03:
```

Comment: What is it then you are getting as response ? Post the full response.

Comment: I'm getting the mail within the ELSE function with all the $_POST variables. Whatever I do, I always get the mail from the ELSE function, so the $res is NEVER VERIFIED!

Comment: Sigh. So what *is* in $res?

Comment: That's not complete. There should at least be a blank line at the end of the headers. You haven't read it all, simple as that.